# Serial communication in C# too slow

Tags: c#

I've got an issue with serial communication. My computer communicates with microcontroller via Bluetooth (HC-05) which should send some bytes of data. Everything works okay except speed of receiving data. It is late, sometimes one second, sometimes even 5-10 seconds. Baud rate was checked. Here is full code.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;

        serialPort1.Open();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Close();
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //dataIN = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
        int count = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        dataIN = Convert.ToInt32(buffer[0]);
        
    }
    private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        textBox1.Text += dataIN.ToString();
        br++;
        if(br == 300)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            br = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This question is missing a lot of detail. Based on the code it looks like it only receives data from the controller. Is the data coming in correct? How do you know that it's late? Are  you able to monitor the controller through other means to see that it's transmitting and just taking time to appear in your program?

Comment: virtual serial port drivers are notorious for being slow/bad/buggy.  Is it possible for the microcontroller to send 1 character per second, and see if the driver can keep up with that?  It could be some sort of buffering in the MC, the bluetooth stack, the driver, or anywhere else.

Comment: I think data coming in is correct, when I do changes in sensor monitoring, it is shown as change in c# app. Only, that change in c# app is too late, for several seconds or more. I tested it how long I keep changing conditions which are measured by sensors and it looks correct.

Comment: I will try to test controller to send one character per second, thanks for advice.

Comment: This code is skirting a firehose problem, calling Invoke() a thousand times per second is not a good idea.  Add textBox1.Update(); and if the delay now seems to be gone then you definitely have this problem.  Focus on writing useful code, spamming a text box with text at such a high rate that a human can never keep up with is not useful.

Comment: I've never had issue with serial port being slow in windows provided events are used.  I would even increase transfer speed to 56K.  I do not think the delay is in the serial communications.  Latency is probably in the code that is displaying results.  I would make  ShowData a timer event that reads data from a buffer every 1/2 second. You are calling  ShowData a lot more often which is causing the latency.

Comment: When I started using button for displaying data, it looks like everything is ok. Probably calling Invoke() was problem. But I'm not well experienced at serial communication. Thanks to everyone.